# Dot Net Core Unit Testing using Xunit -> How to write initialization function for class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I've started work on Unit Testing in Dot Net Core 2.0.
I've written a class to Unit Test controller class of my Web API.

Please find below the code of my Unit Test Class

```
public class ArticlesControllerTests
{
    private ArticlesController _articlesController;

    private Mock<IArticleRepository> _articleRepositoryMock = new Mock<IArticleRepository>();

    public ArticlesControllerTests()
    {
        _articlesController = new ArticlesController(_articleRepositoryMock.Object);
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init()
    {
        AutoMapperInit.Initialize();
    }
}
```

I want to write Init function that will call once and initialize AutoMapper configurations. But `[ClassInitialize]` is not there. I've searched online  but I was not able to find that attribute.

What should I do to make it work for Dot Net Core 2.0.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

Comment: On this documentation, I'm not able to find any `Init` function

Comment: static constructor on test class would work as well

Comment: @Saadi did the static constructor work?

Comment: Yes, It seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Please post answer so that other persons can find the solution of that quesiton.

Comment: Is there any other way to Initialize without using static constructor?

Comment: This question is not sufficiently clear. The title says xUnit is being used. The label says it's nunit. The post that apparently helped you is about mstest. Please clarify what you are using. The three frameworks handle initialization differently and AFAIK ClassInitialize only exists in mstest. Many of us have particular expertise in a single framework and don't bother to answer WRT other frameworks... or if we can't determine what framework you want to use!

Answer (score 2):

Using a *static* constructor on the test class should provide the same behavior

```
public class ArticlesControllerTests {
    private ArticlesController _articlesController;

    private Mock<IArticleRepository> _articleRepositoryMock = new Mock<IArticleRepository>();

    public ArticlesControllerTests() {
        _articlesController = new ArticlesController(_articleRepositoryMock.Object);
    }

    static ArticlesControllerTests() { //<-- static constructor
        AutoMapperInit.Initialize();
    }

    //...
}
```

the static constructor will call once and initialize AutoMapper configurations